# Custom out_of_range exception

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to write an StrExcept exception class that inherits from the base exception class out_of_range by defining its own constructor and a print() method outputting a custom error message to the user.

For now this is my code:

```
class StrExcept: public out_of_range
{
string message;

public:


StrExcept():out_of_range("The value entered is out of range"),message("The value entered is out of range"){};

void print(){
    cout << message;
}

};
```

Inside main method:

```
try
{
    string str="My name";
    // the exception will be fired
    str.substr(11,2);
}
// i want to catch it using this custom class
catch (StrExcept &outOfRange )
{
    // i want to print the error message using print method
   outOfRange.print();

}
```

But why is not working ??? and the program crash ???

Comment: First of all, exceptions are caught by const ref.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you derive from a class does not mean that already existing code (such as the implementation of `basic_string::substr`) will use it. That function will throw `std::out_of_range`. `catch(const StrExcept&)` will only catch an exception of type `StrExcept` or a class derived from it, which is not what was thrown.

Comment: What do you mean, "fix the code"? If you want `substr` to throw a different exception, I thought I made it clear that you *cannot do that*. You can't take someone else's code and make it fire off your own exception types. So what exactly do you want this code to do?

Comment: I meant do i have to do `catch (out_of_range &outOfRange )` and then inside catch block i will create an object of StrExcept  and print out the message ?

Comment: @Jmana: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to just catch the exception and read the message by calling `out_of_range::what` and printing that? Why are you creating an object for something so trivial?

Comment: I know it's so trivial, but that the how problem asked to be,